# sql join with nullable data

Tags: sql, join, one-to-many

I have a posts and users table, and I want that the following code will return a table with a post_count column, if a user has 0 posts it should still say 0, however the code below does not return all the users, only those have have posts.

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(posts.id) post_count 
FROM `posts` 
JOIN  `users` ON `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
GROUP BY(posts.user_id) 
ORDER BY `users`.`id`
```

[image]

Comment: please don't post images of data -- it is hard to read and not very useful since it can't easily be copied and pasted.

Comment: What do you suspect, and what did you try and how did it not work, from reading many hits from googling many clear, concise, specific phrasings of your question? Unlike your current title. What basic SQL intro(s) are you using? Please also read and act on [mcve].

Comment: what do you want

Comment: Mouseover downvote arrow text: "This question does not show any research effort; ...". What is unclear in my comment? (Or Hogan's.) Your question is a basic faq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql you need to use a left join for this:

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(posts.user_id) post_count 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN  posts ON posts.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY(users.id) 
ORDER BY users.id
```

A left join will include all items in the user table and only the records in the posts table that exist.